# Speed of LEFT JOIN in the same table - Mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join

I have a table called PRODUCTS. It has a field of **language**. I want to list all rows of `language = 'es'` which do lack a traduction (corresponding ID) in other language. I have tried the following (id_products is the key relating rows of the same product in different language). It is extremely slow (seconds for a few thousand rows):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    products AS source
    LEFT JOIN products AS target ON source.id_products = target.id_products
    AND source.`language` = 'es'
    AND target.`language` = 'en'
WHERE
    target.id_products IS NULL
```

Comment: are you indexed your fields?

Comment: How much rows do you have in your table ? Does products.id_products and products.language are INDEX-ed ?

Comment: I am very ashamed to say: no. I didn't realize that, I thought it was due to the SQL string. Now it takes 0.0005 seconds. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is happening due to lack of indexes on the table.

Try adding index on (`id_products`,`language`) , that should speed up your query.

In addition you can try to use NOT EXISTS() instead of a left join, maybe it will speed things up a bit as well:

```
SELECT * FROM products t
WHERE t.language = 'es'
 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM products s
                WHERE s.language = 'en'
                  and s.id_products = t.id_products)
```

Comment: My idea would have been to group by id and count occurrences and filter by "lang=es". Then all occurrences with count = 1 is a hit. Not sure if that will be faster , though.

Comment: The index should probably be a composite index on `(id_products, language)`.

Comment: Marginally faster... 0.0004 seconds. In any case, I didn't know about NOT EXISTS, thank you very much, I will use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

**Better index**

It will be faster with the composite index in this order:

```
INDEX(language, id_products)
```

The query will start with `source`.  For that it needs to look at rows with `language = 'es'`, *then* reach into `target`.  For `target` it does not matter which order the index columns are in.

**Don't be mislead by the Query cache**

If you get a time of less than 1 millisecond, the you are probably getting the answer from the "Query cache".  For testing, avoid it by doing

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...
```

There is no use doing `SELECT * ...` since you only want `source` columns, not all the `NULLs` from `target`.  So either say `SELECT source.*` or spell out just the columns you want.

Comment: Yes, I was using SQL_NO_CACHE for speed tests, thanks. It is easy to discover when you have a SQL which lasts almost a second and in the next try it just takes a few milliseconds. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is something weird with where you do the filtering in your query.
You'll get a list of all products, regardless of if source is in 'es' or not. I always recommend to put all the ON-conditions inside parenthesis for clarity.

```
SELECT *
  FROM products AS source
  LEFT JOIN products AS target 
       ON (source.id_products = target.id_products AND target.language = 'en')
 WHERE source.language = 'es'
   AND target.id_products IS NULL;
```

And as other points out you also need an index on language for the filtering on source, and depending on how large your tabell is, also on id_products.

```
alter table products add index search_index (language, id_products);
```

See this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ef44/1) to see it in action.

Comment: No, it is exactly what I want. The 'en' and 'es' are interchanged in your query. The origin is in Spanish, with let's say 3,000 products, and I have only 1,000 of them translated into English. I want to have the 2,000 untranslated products.

Comment: I've changed en/es but my point is still valid. You can't do the filtering on source.language in the join condition.

Comment: I've added a sql fiddle to the answer, it shows the difference between the original query and my suggested change.

Comment: I cannot see the fiddle, it gives a "Build the schema" error.

Comment: Just tried it from the link in the answer, works perfectly.

Comment: Now it works perfectly, maybe some network problem earlier. I see your point, it is completely necessary the source language in the WHERE part. I just had added it with trial and error in my code. I am not completely sure of the lack of the source language in the ON clause. BTW, with so many **chicken**, **burguer** and **churros** I am completely hungry now. :)